# Haskell- Read in user input number string and add them

Tags: haskell

I asked a question earlier and was left with more questions than answers.

I want to be able to do the following:Enter number of integers in a list followed by the number list.

**Examples**

```
4 1 2 3 4
```

OR

```
8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Right now I have the following code that is not working.

```
import Control.Monad


readLn = do
    putStrLn "Enter how many numbers:" -- clearer
    num<-getLine
    numbers<- replicateM num action
    putStrLn("Enter a number: ")
    numberString <- getLine
    return (read numberString :: Int)
    -- here we have numbers :: [Int]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to read/ add/ print a number string in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563414/how-to-read-add-print-a-number-string-in-haskell)

Comment: @Rainbacon That was the OP's earlier question.

Comment: @chepner yes, and this is the exact same question. If the OP doesn't understand the answers they got on the other question, they should comment on the answers they received asking for clarification rather than asking a new question

Answer (score 1):

If you want a single line of input, it doesn't need to include the number of numbers, because you'll just split the line on whitespace to get your list.

```
foo :: IO [Int]
foo = do
   putStr "Enter your numbers, separated by whitespace (e.g. 4 5 3 2): "
   line <- getLine
   return $ map read (words line)
```

`words` splits an input like `2 3 4 5` into the list `["2", "3", "4", "5"]`.

If you want to control how many numbers are entered, with a separate prompt for each number, then you need `replicateM`:

```
-- No error handling or line editing, for simplicity
foo' :: IO [Int]
foo' = do
    putStr "How many numbers?: "
    n <- readLn
    replicateM n $ do
      putStr "Enter a number: "
      readLn
```

`readLn` is equivalent to `fmap read getLine`; you get a line of input, calling `read` on the resulting string.

`replicateM` takes an `IO` action, defined by the nested `do` block, as its second argument. You were passing an undefined variable `action`. That action produces an `IO Int` value, which `replicateM` repeats `n` times an combines the resulting `IO Int` values into a single `IO [Int]` value. (Which is the difference between `replicateM` and `replicate`, which would have produced a list of actions, `[IO Int]`.)

---

Because `foo` and `foo'` are both declared to have type `IO [Int]`, the compiler can infer the proper specific types for the uses of `read` and `readLn`.